# jquery mobile refresh to load map api v3

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

I have to refresh one time the page to load the map.
You can actually have a look in the link below:

**http://metartestmobile.netau.net/template/listview.html**

When i move this line ( 
        `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0-beta2.js"></script>` )

But i wanna use that line..

Here's is the file `listview.html`

```
<html>
        <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/Bootstrap.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.0.min.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0-beta2.js"></script>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div data-role="page" id="my-page" >
                <div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
                    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-divider-theme="f">
                        <li data-role="list-divider">Weather</li>
                        <li data-icon="arrow-r"><a href="map.html" data-transition="flip" >Humidity-Rain</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

and the `map.html`

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/Bootstrap.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
  var infowindow;
  var map;
  function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(38.822590,24.653320);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 6,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="map_canvas" ></div>    
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

jquery mobile use ajax page load for default.
so change this

a href="map.html" data-transition="flip"

to

a href="map.html" data-transition="flip" rel="external"

then jquery mobile refresh hole page.